# PyQT и удаление файла при закрытии приложения

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

При старте программа должна скачивать файл, из которого будет брать информацию для работы, и удалять этот файл после закрытия. Собственно, я написал код: программа стартует, файл скачивается, но код удаляет файл сразу. Собственно вопрос: как привязать удаление файла к моменту закрытия программы?

Мой код:

```
import sys
import requests
import os
import json
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from app_RT_interf import Ui_MainWindow

url = 'http://xxxxxxxxx/data.json'
response = requests.get(url)

with open('data.json', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)

with open('data.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fh: #открываем файл на чтение
    data = json.load(fh) #загружаем из файла данные в словарь data


file.close()

os.remove('data.json')

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

Сам функционал в программе, я думаю, не особо важен - не стал его публиковать. Возможно, мой подход верный, и не стоит менять? Что может пойти не так, кроме ситуации с отсутствием интернета у пользователя?

Comment: Зачем тут вообще файл?

Comment: Там лежит справочник, который подгружается для значений полей comboBox, суть конструкции в том, что бы можно было менять значения при необходимости. Можно было прикрутить sql базу, но ради 20 - 30 значений которые будут менять , дай Бог, раз в год, как то не стоит таких заморочек. А без файлика, при замене справочника, еще раз надо будет всем поменять приложение, кто то обязательно забудет и будут расхождения.

Comment: Спрошу по-другому, почему полученный `json` не использовать сразу как есть без манипуляций с файлом?

Comment: В смысле не удаляя его, а перезаписывая каждый раз? Если я правильно Вас понимаю. Не знаю, просто , что бы у пользователя не болталось на пк.

Comment: Нет. Что мешает сделать так: `data = requests.get(url).content`?

Comment: Через `get` у меня  `for` цикл крутить не хочет, говорит не вижу справочник.

Comment: LivsiMD, что не так в ответе, который вам предоставил @Amgarak ?

Comment: @Amgarak все работает, отметил как решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно определить пользовательский метод закрытия окна. Когда юзер пытается закрыть окно, этот метод будет вызван.

```
def closeEvent(self, event):       # Вызывается при закрытии окна
    self.hide()                    # Скрываем окно
    # Тут ваш код - удаляет файл например
    event.accept()                 # Закрываем окно
```